# input drops down after zooming in and out

Tags: css, html, input

Here I made two simple input fields, but when I zoom in and zoom out on the page (Ctrl + Mouse wheel) somehow the input fields change places, input goes down and up, why it is doing this? How to have them at the same place whether I zoom in or out?

```css
body {
  width: 870px;
}

#col3 {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  /*background-color:#383838;*/
  margin: 20px 10px 10px 30px;
}

form {
  width: 380px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

fieldset {
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px #E37222;
  padding-left: 19px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #EEEEDD;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

span {
  margin-left: -16px;
}

legend {
  background-color: #E37222;
  color: white;
}

input.tt {
  outline: 1px solid #909090;
}

.tt {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="col3">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>eeeee</legend>

      <label for="name">
        <span>rrr:</span>
      </label>
      <input class="tt" type="text" size="34" />
      <br />

      <label class="tt" for="email">
        <span>ttt:</span>
      </label>
      <input class="tt" type="text" size="34" />

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

..........................

Answer (score 2):

Remove `float:left` for `<label>`

```
label{
    display:block;
    width:70px;
    margin-left:10px;

}
```

Comment: if remove it input will go under text, how to have it at same place ?

Comment: Your input is already under the text,  float: left;  doesn't change that, other than fix the problem you want solved. Look [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/yv9Lxjo4/27/)

Comment: @waleedd32 Posted another solution try with that

Answer (score 1):

Either change your markup a little like that, or use flexbox/grid.

```html
<style>

body{
width:870px;

}
#col3{
 width:400px;
 float:left;
 /*background-color:#383838;*/
 margin:20px 10px 10px 30px;

}
form{
 width:380px;
 margin:auto;
 padding:5px;
 border:solid 1px white;
}
fieldset{
 margin:auto;
 border:solid 1px #E37222;
 padding-left: 19px;
    padding-top: 15px;
 background-color:   #EEEEDD;
}

label{
 display:block;
    width: 100%;
}

label div{
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 68px;
    display: inline-block;
}

legend{
background-color:#E37222;
color:white;
}


input.tt{
    outline: 1px solid #909090;
}
.tt{
    margin-top:8px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="col3">
 <form ">
 <fieldset >
   <legend>eeeee</legend>

   <label  for="name"><div>rrr:</div><input class="tt type="text" size="34" /> </label>
   
   <br/>  

   <label class="tt"for="email"><div>ttt:</div><input class="tt" type="text" size="34" /></label>
   
 
  
   
   
  
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </div>
 
 
 
</body>
```

Comment: can u change it to flexbox, havent used that before, because with this one u took away width of label

Comment: You can add a width of label back (witch will be the sum of span and input field)

Comment: i added but it changeed that completely text went inside input

Comment: so, changed a few things. Hope this is what you had in mind

Answer (score 1):

Try with This

```
.youclassname{
 display:flex;
}

<div class="yourclassname">
  <label  for="name"><span>rrrrrr rrrrrr:</span></label>
  <input class="tt type="text" size="34" /> 
</div>
```